# Would vs Would have

Tags: would-have-been

Which one of them is the most appropriate - 
1) If she didn't like him , why would she date him ?
2) If she didn't like him , why would she have been dating him ?
3) If she didn't like him , why would she have dated him ?

Implication must be that she doesn't like him ( a present situation) yet she is dating him , and she has been dating him for a while .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first one is the most commonly used phrase among others.

Comment: The OP does not ask for the most popular. You have not included any references or supporting evidence. The three variants have slightly different nuances.